# Calling virtual function in subclass from superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I know this question must have been covered endless of times, but I've searched the previous questions, and nothing seems to pop.

It's about inheritance and virtual functions i C++. I have a problem with calling virtual functions in subclasses from the superclass.

Let me give an example. Start of with three classes, which inherit from each other.

```
class A {

    void foo() { bar() }
    virtual void bar() { }

};

class B : public A {

    virtual void bar() { }

};

class C : public B {

    virtual void bar() { // do something }

};
```

Now I wanna have a variable declared as B* but instantiated as C*.

```
B* myObject = new C();
myObject->foo();
```

When I do this, and call foo() on myObject, then A::foo() is calling bar(). But only B::bar() is called, not C::Bar() - which in reality myObject is, even though it's declared as B, which again affects that "// do nothing" doesn't get executed.

How do I tell A::foo(), that it needs to look at lowest implementation?

Makes sense?

// Trenskow

EDIT:

C::Foo is not the problem. Foo is being called in class A, as it's the only place it's implemented. The problem arises, when A:Foo calls Bar(). Then B:Bar is called and not C::Bar.

Maybe the problem is, that in my implementation, I only get a void* pointer to the object in A.

Like this:

```
void A:Foo(void *a) {

    A* tmpA = static_cast<A*> (a);
    tmpA->bar();

}
```

Now the compiler thinks, that tmpA is an A. But somehow it manages to figure that it's a B*, and calls B::Bar, when in fact tmpA is a C* and it should be calling C::Bar.

Comment: If you posted real code then we could tell that the problem is. You don't need to do anything special. If the syntax errors are fixed, the code (`myObject->foo();`) will call `C::bar()`.

Comment: ... but if I were to guess, either `C` does not really override `bar` (having a different signature), or you are slicing the object somewhere (by doing something like `*variable = *myObject;`

Comment: I still don't buy it. Why wouldn't C::bar() be called? Can you post the actual code?

Comment: You probably should try to create a minimum example that exhibits the problem. If you can't reproduce the results, compare your minimal example to what your code is doing. Chances are you'll figure it out yourself.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, and I have no clue on why this happens. I've experienced it before, but rewriting classes from scratch seem to have fixed it. At the moment, I'm looking for a clue, so I came across this. There must be someone somewhere who thinks: "I experienced that and found the solution; you're probably doing <this and that> wrong." -If so, please post a clue.

Comment: May have found the cause of my problem (this time). In my constructor of A, I call B->bar(), but the object is probably not fully constructed yet, which could be why B->bar() is not being called and A->bar() is being called instead.

Comment: YEP. That's it. I can't call a subclass' method from within the constructor of the superclass. I guess I've gotten too used to ObjC...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following prints "A::foo C::bar" as expected.  Are you getting something different?  `B::bar` is never called because `C` is the actual runtime type of the object.  In `C::bar`, you could call `B::bar` explicitly by adding `B::bar();` to its body.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void foo() { cout << "A::foo "; bar(); }
    virtual void bar() { }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void bar() { cout << "B::bar" << endl; }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    virtual void bar() { cout << "C::bar" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B* c = new C();
    c->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void A:Foo(void *a) {

    A* tmpA = static_cast<A*> (a);
    tmpA->bar();

}
```

This is undefined behaviour. You cannot cast a B* to a void*, then cast that void* back to an A*. If you want it to work properly, you have to ditch the void*. Alternatively, you could try dynamic_cast.

Comment: Or you cast B* to A* first and then cast A* to void*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mistyped your last block of code and the names match:

```
B* variable = new C();
variable->foo();
```

Then the C::Foo method is being called or you are using a terribly bad compiler.

(This also assumes that you don't actually have a compiler error in C::Foo, and that the comment is actually something like `std::cout << "Hi mom!" << std::endl;`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean:

```
B* myObject = new C();
myObject->foo(); // not variable->foo()

class A
{
public:
    void foo() { bar(); }
    virtual void bar() { std::cout << "A"; };
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void bar() { std::cout << "B";};
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual void bar() { std::cout << "C"; }
};
```

This prints 'C' as expected.

Comment: Oh shoot yea. Changed the variable name in an edit, not to just call it variable. Must have forgotten the second line. Edited

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow. You're saying

> But only B::bar() is called, not
>   C::Bar()

No. You invoked the constructor of class C, which means that the vtable makes bar() point to C::bar(), so calling foo() in this case would go straight to C::bar().

If you want to force A::foo() to explicitly only call A's implementation, you can do that by just writing

```
void foo() { A::bar(); }
```

What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

what compiler are you using? Visual Studio (IIRC) usually has the runtime type information turned off by default so maybe its just something simple as that?